# Parse: change a pointer's value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

For example, I have two class `Player` and `Game`, and `Game` has a field `player` which is a pointer to `Player`. As Parse documentation says, `save` is recursive, so I assume that I can save a `player` by only saving a `game`, just like:

```
let player = PFObject(className: "Player")
player["name"] = ABC
let game = PFObject(className: "Game")
game["player"] = player
game["round"] = 1
game.saveInBackground()
```

Is this true?

Ok, now assuming that is true, then what about changing the `player`'s `name` by only saving `game`? Like:

```
let player = game["player"] as! PFObject
player["name"] = BCD
game["round"] = 2
game.saveInBackground()
```

Could you please answer these two questions? Thank you.

Another question: If I want to get the `player["name"]`, do I need to use `includeKey("player")` when querying the `game`?

Comment: You can test it - do they appear in the web interface? Which documentation are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it's true about the recursive saving when you save an object that includes pointers to other objects. All of the pointed-to objects will be saved. Since `game` points to `player`, `player` will also be saved when `game` is saved.
2. The changes in a related object, such as the player's name, should also be saved based on (1).
3. Since queries do not automatically retrieve related objects in a corresponding recursive manner, you are correct about needing to use includeKey to retrieve the related Player object when retrieving a Game.