# Parse / iOS: I save the parent object, but the child object did not get updated

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, save, parent-child

I have a simple parse schema

**Class AClass**

title (string) | childs (array of pointer of class b)

```
import Parse

class AClass : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

  @NSManaged var title: String
  @NSManaged var childs: [BClass]?

  override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
  }

  static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "AClass"
  }
}
```

**Class BClass**

message (string)

```
import Parse


class BClass : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

  @NSManaged var message: String

  override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
  }

  static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "BClass"
  }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
BClass.registerSubclass()
AClass.registerSubclass()
```

ViewController.swift e.g. I tried ...

```
    let query = AClass.query()
    query?.includeKey("childs")
    query?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (parent, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let parentObj = parent as? AClass
            parentObj.childs?.last?.message = "Changed"
            parentObj.saveInBackground()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    })
```

I thought that parse would save recursive. First the parent object and all changed child objects. But I can't see any changes in the parse dashboard of the message (BClass).

I am using Parse (1.12.0) with Swift and PFSubclassing for my classes. Any ideas?

Comment: I thought Parse will save changes in related objects that have unsaved changes. Like parse saves object recursively....

Comment: Do you get an error message from the save?

Comment: No nothing. The completion handler says successful. But the modified child isn't saved (dashboard), only the parent. It's weird

Comment: I am missing this behavior described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717620/parse-change-a-pointers-value/33718604#33718604

Comment: Have you pinned the object(s)?

Comment: No, I don't use local data store yet